# Adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA causes cannot access module before initialization

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, web-component, stenciljs

After adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA I see:

`Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SomethingModule' before initialization`

I'm working in Angular, Ionic 4, and when I add `,schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` to the `@NgModule` section of a module definition it throws the above error.

In this case its a "tab" module from Ionic Tabs. I've isolated it just to this change. If I don't put the schemas change in, Angular will complain that I *NEED* CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in this page's (tab's) module definition. But pukes as soon as I put it in.

And yes, I have `import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';` above.

This was not a problem when doing the same thing in app.module.ts and using the element in app.component.html

Comment: hi, did you find a solution do this ? I don't have CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA but when loading a module via a menu I have the same error message. Using angular 8 + ionic 4